# WebDAV Incorrectly Opening PHP Files

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange site to ask this on, but I think it's the closest related to the topic.

I'm running a WebDAV server using Apache's mod_dav on Linux (Ubuntu). I've successfully connected to it with Windows 7. However, when I open the PHP files in an editor, I don't get their source code, but instead their output. Other files, including images, open correctly. Is there any way to fix this issue?

My Apache config:

```
<Location /webdav/>
        DAV On
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "WebDAV"
        AuthDigestDomain /webdav/
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav/.htdigest
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Please show us your Apache configuration section for WebDAV?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post to include my config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove content type associations for PHP files:

```
RemoveType .php
```

If it doesn't work, remove handler:

```
RemoveHandler .php
ForceType text/plain
```

or disable PHP:

```
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. However, strangely, I can open some PHP files correctly, but not others. The ones I can't open are the ones I opened before I changed the options. Is there some sort of cache I need to clear?

Comment: Nevermind, I've decided not to use this method. However, this fixed the problem for the other files, so I'll mark it as the solution.